# Dynamically Adding a Field to Django modelformset ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with

Tags: django, django-forms

In my app, I have to dynamically add a field to the `modelformset` in the `__init__` method of the custom `modelformset` by extending `BaseModelFormSet`.

```
class BaseInvoiceFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        excluded_fields = kwargs.pop('excluded_fields', None)
        super(BaseInvoiceFormSet, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
           form.fields.update({'min_unit_share': forms.IntegerField(validators = [validate_positive,] ) })
           form.fields.move_to_end('min_unit_share', last=False) # Note that self.fields is an ordereddict.  To move an item to the front of an ordered dict in Python 3.0+
```

I get

```
Exception Type:   ValidationError
Exception Value:  ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

When I comment out the dynamically added field, the error goes away.  So, the post method of the class view calls the `__init__` method as expected.  But, for some reason it thinks that I am changing the `ManagementForm` data. The question is how to get around or resolve this issue.  Is there a way to pop out the added field before calling

> super(BaseInvoiceFormSet, self).**init**(*args,**kwargs)

Note that it seems all the `modelformset` data is passed through using `*args`. It is sitting at `args[0]` and I could not pop the additional field using `args[0].pop('min_unit_share')`

Also, to make things simple, in my template, I use:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}   < Edit 1: formset.management_form is there
{% for form in formset %}
    {{ form.as_p }}             
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `{{ formset.management_form }}` in your template.
The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform) explain it.

so in your template:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
    {{ form.as_p }}             
{% endfor %}
```

## EDITED

so, i found another reason why that error occurs, see this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946143/managementform-data-is-missing-or-has-been-tampered-with-error-when-loading-mu) 
hope it can fix your error :)

Comment: check my edited answer, hope it's useful for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment and help. I'm using class-based view and instantiated the formset using request.POST only in the def post(self, *args, **kwargs) of the view